# Display correlation matrix using axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I used to plot my correlation matrix like:

```
corr_matrix = np.corrcoef(W)
    plt.matshow(corr_matrix)
    labels = ['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5', 'P6', 'P7', 'P8', 'P9', 'P10', 'P11', 'P12', 'P13', 'P14', 'P15', ]
    plt.xticks(range(0,15),labels)
    plt.yticks(range(0,15),labels)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.show()
```

Now I'm working with some provided code which is plotting different things in 2 figures over time using the `axes.draw()` method.

The plotting of the figures is done with:

```
fig_1, axes_1 = plt.subplots(yl,5)  # fig 1
fig_2, axes_2 = plt.subplots(5,1)   # fig 2
```

and at some point after setting the data `plt.draw()` is used to redraw the images.

I've tried to add another figure like:

```
fig_cor, axes_cor = plt.subplots(1,1)
```

and use

```
        axes_cor.imshow(corr_matrix)
        labels = ['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5', 'P6', 'P7', 'P8', 'P9', 'P10', 'P11', 'P12', 'P13', 'P14',
                  'P15'] 
        axes_cor.set_xticks(range(0, 15), labels)
        axes_cor.set_yticks(range(0, 15), labels)
        # axes_cor.colorbar()
        plt.draw()
```

The image is displayed, but my labels are not and when I'm trying to draw the colorbar too I get `'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'colorbar'`. Can anyone help me solve this?

What I want to display:

[image]

What I get:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in imshow the ticks are created that dont match the label elements. May be there is an elegant solution, but the example below also achieves it.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

corr_matrix= np.random.rand(20,20)
fig_cor, axes_cor = plt.subplots(1,1)
fig_cor.set_size_inches(6, 6)

labels = ['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5', 'P6', 'P7', 'P8', 'P9', 'P10', 'P11', 'P12', 'P13', 'P14','P15'] 

myimage = axes_cor.imshow(corr_matrix)

plt.colorbar(myimage)

axes_cor.set_xticks(np.arange(0,corr_matrix.shape[0], corr_matrix.shape[0]*1.0/len(labels)))
axes_cor.set_yticks(np.arange(0,corr_matrix.shape[1], corr_matrix.shape[1]*1.0/len(labels)))

axes_cor.set_xticklabels(labels)
axes_cor.set_yticklabels(labels)

plt.draw()
```

results in

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Looks right. But what about the colorbar?

Comment: forgot about the colorbar. included in the latest edit.

Comment: Thank you. But why does your colorbar have so many colors, and mine only has from blue to yellow?

Comment: Its a different colormap.

Comment: Where do you set that?

Comment: I think u have virdis and in my plot i use jet.

Comment: I noticed that if I show the correlation matrix multiple times, the colorbar is added to the other figures as well. I will just plot it once.